# Producing 2D array from a 1D array in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

Does anyone know if there is a way to produce a 2D array from a 1D array, where the rows in the 2D are generated by repeating the corresponding elements in the 1D array.

I.e.:

```
1D array      2D array

  |1|       |1 1 1 1 1|
  |2|       |2 2 2 2 2|
  |3|  ->   |3 3 3 3 3|
  |4|       |4 4 4 4 4|
  |5|       |5 5 5 5 5|
```

Answer (score 9):

In the spirit of bonus answers, here are some of my own:

Let `A = (1:5)'`

1. Using indices [faster than repmat]:

   ```
   B = A(:, ones(5,1))
   ```
2. Using matrix outer product:

   ```
   B = A*ones(1,5)
   ```
3. Using bsxfun() [not the best way of doing it]

   ```
   B = bsxfun(@plus, A, zeros(1,5))
   %# or
   B = bsxfun(@times, A, ones(1,5))
   ```

Comment: @merv: you can read more about these "Techniques for Improving Performance" at http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f8-784135.html#br8fs0d-4    @woodchips: the first example you gave is the same as the one given by gnovice. The second is not really a general repmat alternative, only a special case for this particular `A`..

Answer (score 8):

You can do this using the [REPMAT](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/repmat.html) function:

```
>> A = (1:5).'

A =

     1
     2
     3
     4
     5

>> B = repmat(A,1,5)

B =

     1     1     1     1     1
     2     2     2     2     2
     3     3     3     3     3
     4     4     4     4     4
     5     5     5     5     5
```

**EDIT: BONUS ANSWER! ;)**

For your example, [REPMAT](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/repmat.html) is the most straight-forward function to use. However, another cool function to be aware of is [KRON](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/kron.html), which you could also use as a solution in the following way:

```
B = kron(A,ones(1,5));
```

For small vectors and matrices [KRON](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/kron.html) may be *slightly* faster, but it is quite a bit slower for larger matrices.

Answer (score 1):

[repmat](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/repmat.html)(a, [1 n]), but you should also take a look at [meshgrid](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/meshgrid.html).

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
a = [1 2 3 4 5]'
l = size(a)
for i=2:5
    a(1:5, i) = a(1:5)
```

The loop just keeps appending columns to the end.

Comment: For small matrices this solution is faster, but for larger sizes repmat is a much better solution. (With a 1000x1000 matrix, repmat is 500+ times faster!)

Comment: I agree, my solution is a pretty naive on, using repmat is a much better/more elegant solution in general.