# MATLAB: Filling a matrix with each column being the same

Tags: matlab, matrix, concatenation

I am trying to create a matrix that is 3 x n, with each of the columns being the same. What's the easiest way of achieving it? Concatenation?

Comment: It is not clear.  Do you want [1 1 1; 2 2 2; 3 3 3] where the columns are identical or do you want [1 2 3;1 2 3;1 2 3] where each column is the same number?

Comment: similar Q: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209207/producing-2d-array-from-a-1d-array-in-matlab

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After

```
n=7
x=[1;2;3]
```

it's either

```
repmat(x,[1 n])
```

or

```
x(:,ones(1,n))
```

Comment: I'd say the index-based solution is the way to go (and it's generally faster).

Comment: Thanks. repmat is the keyword that I was looking for, but forgot.

Answer (score 3):

(Octave can be considered as an open source/free version of MATLAB)

```
octave-3.0.3:2> rowvec = [1:10]
rowvec =

    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10

octave-3.0.3:3> [rowvec; rowvec; rowvec]
ans =

    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10
    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10
    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10
```

Use `repmat` if the number of rows is large.

```
octave-3.0.3:7> repmat(rowvec, 10, 1)
ans =

    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10
    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10
    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10
    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10
    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10
    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10
    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10
    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10
    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10
    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10
```

Answer (score 2):

Use multiplication with a 1 x 3 matrix of ones

eg, `x * [1 1 1]`

Edit:

In Octave:

```
    octave-3.0.3.exe:1> x = [1;2;3;4]
x =

   1
   2
   3
   4


octave-3.0.3.exe:5> x * [1 1 1]
ans =

   1   1   1
   2   2   2
   3   3   3
   4   4   4
```

Comment: I think @KennyTM might mean it gives `[x x x]` (where `x` is a column vector), when the OP wants `[x; x; x]` (where `x` is a row vector, as in his answer), but the question is slightly ambiguous, hence my answer.

Comment: Ah, I see. I guess it also depends what his input is. You could always use 'transpose' to switch between our solutions.